# Cannot kill stopped job - no job control in subprocess?

Tags: shell, jobs, kill, job-control

I'm working with ash/dash and try to kill a subprocess - which doesn't seem to respond:

`sh &` opens a subprocess and `jobs` delivers `[1]+ Stopped (tty Input)    sh`.

But trying to kill this Job with `kill %1` or `kill 26672` doesn't work. `jobs` delivers `[1]+ Stopped (tty Input)    sh` again.

After putting the job to foreground with `fg` opens the shell for input. Neither `ctrl+c` nor `ctrl+z` are working but I can kill the process with `exit` or `kill -SIGKILL $$` respectively stop/suspend the process with `kill -STOP $$` (there is no `suspend`-command in ash).

On the other hand - doing this with i.e. `sleep 100` works fine till I `fg` and stop the process with `ctr+z`. Then I'm not able to `kill` this stopped job.

So what am I missing and what could be the solution to kill a stopped job? Do I have to deal with `set -m` and how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What operating system is it?

Comment: Basically **Busybox** - which offers the inherent Almqvist-Shell (ash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rung the Stopped process by `kill -SIGCONT %number`and also if you need to kill that process you can kill it by `kill -SIGTERM %number.`Try this I think this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the solution. Actually `kill -SIGKILL %1` or `kill -KILL %1` did (killed) the job. In the case of using ash the second command worked. To see the possible signals a shell supports the command `kill -l` helps. Instead of `-SIGKILL` or `-KILL` also `-9` can be used. By the way: `SIGTERM`didn't kill the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

kill -9 $(jobs -p)

Or, just do exit command to logout, it will automatically killed the stopped jobs